# eth_keys how to get a string public key so that I can put it into JSON

Tags: python, public-key-encryption

I have a private - public key signature that works correctly:

```
print(signature.verify_msg(bytes(transaction_hash.hexdigest().encode('utf-8')), first_wallet['public_key']))
```

> verify_signature:
>   0xf9671943931afb93e1613eb5d73a77ed961653f70562884709d45ffa774fa7f756b7e8b8a4bd11ffe71448eedddfc10e7dbcd4b069477c7665e6a978347b6e42
>
> True

But I need to json serialize the public key so that the node can do the verifying, I have tryied many things. The first error is:

> TypeError: Object of type 'PublicKey' is not JSON serializable

Then, if I serialize it with `first_wallet['public_key'].to_hex()`, when the node uses that public key to verify the message I get:

> eth_keys.exceptions.ValidationError: Unexpected uncompressed public
>   key length: Expected 64, but got 130 bytes

Comment: if you convert to bytes, the length is 64, the length of your hex string is 130.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you serialize it to bytes, it might be reading the length of the hex. I have a few examples below that are json serializable which the server may except. Without knowing which library your interfacing with on the other end i decided to show a few examples.

```
In [587]: bytes.fromhex(hex(first_wallet['public_key'])[2:])                                                                                                  
Out[587]: b'\xf9g\x19C\x93\x1a\xfb\x93\xe1a>\xb5\xd7:w\xed\x96\x16S\xf7\x05b\x88G\t\xd4_\xfawO\xa7\xf7V\xb7\xe8\xb8\xa4\xbd\x11\xff\xe7\x14H\xee\xdd\xdf\xc1\x0e}\xbc\xd4\xb0iG|ve\xe6\xa9x4{nB'
```

```
In [572]: len('0xf9671943931afb93e1613eb5d73a77ed961653f70562884709d45ffa774fa7f756b7e8b8a4bd11ffe71448eedddfc10e7dbcd4b069477c7665e6a978347b6e42')           
Out[572]: 130

In [573]: len(b'\xf9g\x19C\x93\x1a\xfb\x93\xe1a>\xb5\xd7:w\xed\x96\x16S\xf7\x05b\x88G\t\xd4_\xfawO\xa7\xf7V\xb7\xe8\xb8\xa4\xbd\x11\xff\xe7\x14H\xee\xdd\xdf\xc1\x0e}\xbc\xd4\xb0iG|ve\xe6\xa9x4{nB')                                                                                                                 
Out[573]: 64
```

```
encoded = base64.encodebytes( b'\xf9g\x19C\x93\x1a\xfb\x93\xe1a>\xb5\xd7:w\xed\x96\x16S\xf7\x05b\x88G\t\xd4_\xfawO\xa7\xf7V\xb7\xe8\xb8\xa4\xbd\x11\xff\xe7\x14H\xee\xdd\xdf\xc1\x0e}\xbc\xd4\xb0iG|ve\xe6\xa9x4{nB')  

encoded                                                                                                                                               
b'+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl\n5ql4NHtuQg==\n'

encoded.decode('ascii')                                                                                                                               
'+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl\n5ql4NHtuQg==\n'

In [12]: json.dumps('+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl\n5ql4NHtuQg==\n')                                           
Out[12]: '"+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl\\n5ql4NHtuQg==\\n"'
```

or

```
base64.b64encode(b'\xf9g\x19C\x93\x1a\xfb\x93\xe1a>\xb5\xd7:w\xed\x96\x16S\xf7\x05b\x88G\t\xd4_\xfawO\xa7\xf7V\xb7\xe8\xb8\xa4\xbd\x11\xff\xe7\x14H\x
    ...: ee\xdd\xdf\xc1\x0e}\xbc\xd4\xb0iG|ve\xe6\xa9x4{nB')
b'+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl5ql4NHtuQg=='

json.dumps(b'+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl5ql4NHtuQg==') 


In [22]: json.dumps('+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl5ql4NHtuQg==')                                               
Out[22]: '"+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl5ql4NHtuQg=="'

In [24]: base64.b64decode('"+WcZQ5Ma+5PhYT611zp37ZYWU/cFYohHCdRf+ndPp/dWt+i4pL0R/+cUSO7d38EOfbzUsGlHfHZl5ql4NHtuQg=="')                                       
Out[24]: b'\xf9g\x19C\x93\x1a\xfb\x93\xe1a>\xb5\xd7:w\xed\x96\x16S\xf7\x05b\x88G\t\xd4_\xfawO\xa7\xf7V\xb7\xe8\xb8\xa4\xbd\x11\xff\xe7\x14H\xee\xdd\xdf\xc1\x0e}\xbc\xd4\xb0iG|ve\xe6\xa9x4{nB'
```

Comment: The second one worked. Although json.dumps like that gives me `Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`